# Extract a method's implementation with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, runtime

Lets say I have two classes, `ClassA` and `ClassB` as follow :

```
class ClassA
{
    public void MyFunctionA(ClassB classB)
    {
        classB.MyActionB = () => this.MySecretFunctionA(3); // "Hard coded 3"
    }

    private void MySecretFunctionA(int anInt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(anInt.ToString());
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    public Action MyActionB;

    public void MyFunctionB()
    {
        MyActionB();
    }

    private void MySecretFunctionB()
    {
        // Here
    }
}
```

Is it possible for `ClassB` to "know" exactly, at runtime, what MyActionB will do when called? For example, is it possible for `ClassB` to extract "3", once again, at runtime? (see the "Hard coded 3" comment.)

`ClassA` and `ClassB` are in different assemblies, and if it makes a difference (I don't think so though) `ClassB`'s assembly is loaded at runtime.

In the title, I suggested reflection, but if it's not the proper term in this circumstance, I'll edit it. If it is possible, just an idea of how would be nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the IL for a method, via

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody(v=vs.90).aspx

However, whether this is any practical use depends on just how specific your use case is. There isn't a way to access or reverse engineer the syntax tree at runtime as this information isn't saved in the metadata.

Going forward perhaps something will be possible using the new Roslyn compiler, when it's released.